# UI Freezes when calling .Show on new Window

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

In my application, I open the MainWindow from LoginWindow. When I call MainWindow.Show(), LoginWindow UI freezes. I've tried:

- await Task.Run() but this won't work because I need to open the window on the UI thread
- await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke but this doesn't seem to work asynchronously

I must be misunderstanding something fundamental about how async programming works.

```
public async void LoginAsync(object pbx)
    {
        VisLoginLoading = Visibility.Visible;
        var passwordBox = pbx as PasswordBox;
        string enteredPassword = passwordBox.Password;

        string cmdQuery = $"SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, AccessLevel, ALERTS, STORES FROM Tbl_UserAccounts WHERE USERNAME = @Username";

        try
        {
            string errorMsg = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(PosConString))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdQuery, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Username;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string password = reader.GetString(1);

                            if (DoesPasswordMatch(password, enteredPassword))
                            {
                                UserAccount.Username = (reader[0] == DBNull.Value) ? null : reader.GetString(0);
                                UserAccount.Access = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(UserAccess), reader.GetInt32(2)) ? (UserAccess)reader.GetInt32(2) : UserAccess.Unknown;
                                UserAccount.Alerts = (reader[3] == DBNull.Value) ? false : reader.GetBoolean(3);
                                UserAccount.Stores = (reader[4] == DBNull.Value) ? null : HelperMethods.ReturnWordList(reader.GetString(4));
                                return String.Empty;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return "Password is incorrect";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "User does not exist";
                    }
                }

                return "Failed to login";
            });

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
            {
                LoadApp();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(errorMsg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Failed to login\n\n{ex}");
        }

        VisLoginLoading = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public async void LoadApp()
    {
        VisLoginLoading = Visibility.Visible;

        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                mainWindow.Show();
            }));

        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window.Title == "Login") window.Close();
        }
        VisLoginLoading = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201496/discussion-on-question-by-david-andrew-thorpe-ui-freezes-when-calling-show-on-n).

Comment: Think this is because of the Dispatcher and current frame. Your Main window pushed a frame on the dispatcher and that is now blocking the Login Window frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's logically, that GUI thread freezes.
Look, you start a long running operation on GUI thread with `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. So all other "user" of this thread have to wait until it's available, to handle their(LoginWindow) operations on it. What you can do in this situation?

You can start another GUI thread, which will take care about new Window:

```
public void LoadApp()
{
    VisLoginLoading = Visibility.Visible;

    var thr = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.Show();
        mw.Closed += (sender, e) => mw.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    thr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thr.Start();

    //Move this logic to the MainWindow, after initialization is done.
    //foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    //{
    //    if (window.Title == "Login") window.Close();
    //}
    VisLoginLoading = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Now you can start a `MainWindow`, but you have to solve another challenge (I think) - notify `VisLoginLoading` the initialization is finished. But it's another question. So your UI will not freez.
See also [Threading Model.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

**Update:**

In MainWindow use:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>
{
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window.Title == "Login") window.Close();
    }
}));
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Error happens on MainWindow InitializeComponent: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: If the error occurs by access to the `Application.Current.Windows`, then use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` for this loop. See my update.

Comment: The error happens when I use the code exactly as above. I'm not sure what you say needs to change?

Comment: With the code above I could start Window2 from Window1 and close Window1 after long running(with `Thread.Sleep`) initialization of Window2 was finished. There were no issues with access on objects within Windows2 accept `Application.Current.Windows`. This I have solved with using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. If it doesn't work, then send an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Within a test app, your your code works but for some reason it doesn't work in my main application. I haven't been able to recreate the issue (yet). Your answer does technically answer my question though so I'll mark it and upvote

Comment: I'm wondering it doesn't work by you. Do you create some controls, which being used in `MainWindow`, on another thread? I'm thinking also about templates as static resources. Check the app.xaml.